# Passing values in form Box

Tags: php, html

I got some values from a previous PHP file

EX:

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['title'];
$value1 = $_GET['name']; 
$value2 = $_GET['age']; 
$value3 = $_GET['institution'];
?>
```

Now i have a form field like following

```
<body>
<form action="pare.php" method="post">  
<label>Title:</label>
<input type="text" name="title" size="50"/><br/>     
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" size="50"/><br/> 
 <label>age:</label> 
 <input type="text" name="age" size="50"/> <br/>
 <label>Institution:</label> 
<select name="institution">
<option value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="abc">abc</option> 
</select><br/>
<label></label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" /><br/>
</form>
</body>
```

Now what i want to do is display the values in a PHP file($value,$value1...)in their respective form field boxes.

If the user wants to edit those values($value,$value1...) he must be able to edit and submit those values.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['title']) ?> />
```

note the use of htmlspecialchars. It prevents any HTML metacharacters (`"` in particular) within the data from 'breaking' your form - e.g... it prevents HTML injection attacks.

Comment: Hey thnks for the answer ,but i think by declaring Value = "" to some constant sets it to a fix value . For Example if the customer wants to change value passed in the text box this cannot be done as value of that form is fixed..i do not want to this to happen..

Comment: setting a value only sets a DEFAULT value for the field. the user can still change it all they want. setting the 'disabled' attribute prevents the user from changing it.

Comment: hmm..but it did not work for me ..the values were not changing :(

Comment: You can't click on one of the input fields and type a new value? There must be something preventing that in your site/code, because setting a `value` on an input field is how every single website since the dawn of the web has pre-filled forms with default values.

Comment: HTML looks ok. Your database call is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Other than that, no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are wanting to replace the null `value` attribute with the value obtained from your PHP code.  In that event, you will want to simply add the `value` attribute and set it to the desired PHP variable:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['nameVar']); ?>">
```

Comment: Hey thnks for the answer ,but i think by declaring Value = "" to some constant sets it to a fix value . For Example if the customer wants to change value passed in the text box this cannot be done as value of that form is fixed..i do not want to this to happen..

Comment: Setting the value attribute will only set the default value for the corresponding object.  If someone modifies the value, then the new value can be passed via a form submit or through the use of Javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question correctly, and if I do why not just set the `value` attribute on your inputs?

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'name' size = '50' value = '<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($_GET['name'])); ?>'>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $htmlvalue= htmlspecialchars($_GET['title']); ?>
```

before the textbox element

```
<input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="<?php echo htmlvalue; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the same form, except add a value attribute.

for instance

`<input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="<?php echo($value); ?>"/>`